# Why do most United Kingdom visas restrict working as a sportsperson?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, visa

The majority of UK visas, for example the [British National (Overseas) visa](https://www.gov.uk/british-national-overseas-bno-visa), and the [Graduate visa](https://www.gov.uk/graduate-visa), appear to include a restriction on working as a professional sportsperson:

Why did the British government decide to disallow most visa holders from working as (and seemingly only as) a sportsperson?

Comment: Can you add some background to support this belief?  For example, someone admitted as a highly skilled worker can only work in the job for which they are highly skilled.  A computer programmer cannot work as a sportsperson nor as a street sweeper.

Comment: To stop unscrupulous pseudo-employers from bringing over large numbers of fake sportsmen in order to subvert the immigration system

Comment: @Valorum why sportspersons in particular?

Comment: @theonlygusti - Because they play infrequently, which means there's a good reason for them not to be available for employment checks. Plus they don't need to have any demonstrable qualifications.

Comment: There was the funny story of the Sri Lanka national handball team disappearing when they were in Germany - and then on further inspection it turned out that there was no Sri Lankan national handball team

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's to ensure that the [International Sportsperson visa](https://www.gov.uk/sportsperson-visa) is the sole route for sportspeople coming to work in the UK. Kevin Foster, then Parliamentary Under-Secretary of State for Safe and Legal Migration, has answered a written question on the topic which explains the underlying reasons for this decision:

> The International Sportsperson route is the single work route for
> overseas sportspeople in the UK and is underpinned by a governing body
> endorsement (GBE) process. Each sport’s governing body’s GBE criteria
> are set in consultation with the Home Office and involve a skills
> assessment against which migrants are endorsed for a visa application,
> ensuring they are elite and internationally established sportspeople.
>
> The restriction on work as a professional sportsperson seeks to
> protect the integrity of the GBE process, in turn encouraging
> investment in resident sportspeople and protecting opportunities for
> home-grown talent.
> <sub>[UIN 245, tabled on 10 May 2022](https://questions-statements.parliament.uk/written-questions/detail/2022-05-10/245/)</sub>

Comment: You might think that this same logic would apply to any field of endeavor, but it really doesn't. Professional sportspeople, largely due to events like the Olympics, are more heavily tied to their countries of origin than people in almost any other profession.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Additionally, the GBE process does not make as much sense in most other professions. Most professions are either locally or regionally regulated (lawyers, doctors, general contractors, etc), in which case endorsement makes little sense unless the regulations are equivalent, or have no associated governing body at all, in which case such endorsement is impossible.

Comment: Of course one might ask why does the UK government care about "opportunities for home-grown talent" vs. maximizing the number of medals won by UK athletes which is what most voters actually care about.

Comment: @JonathanReez to begin with, a visa does not grant citizenship (in fact you can give visas to your citizens) so people in the UK under that visa can not represent the UK at the Olympics or other events.

Comment: @SJuan76 athletes are well known for being granted citizenship if they reach the highest levels of sports.

Comment: @JonathanReez - I can't think of any examples (apart from maybe Zola Budd) where some established athlete was given UK citizenship and catapulted into a national team.